# How to insert an XML object into an unordered list

Tags: javascript, xml, list, parsing, unordered

i just asked a very similar question but wiht Json, now i'm having trouble with xml.

XML:

```
<dinosaurs>
 <dinosaur>
  <name>Staurikosaurus</name>
  <group>Saurischia</group>
  <diet>Carnivore</diet>
  <period>Triassic</period>
 </dinosaur>
 <dinosaur>
  <name>Diplodocus</name>
  <group>Saurischia</group>
  <diet>Herbivore</diet>
  <period>Jurassic</period>
 </dinosaur>
 <dinosaur>
  <name>Stegosaurus</name>
  <group>Ornithischia</group>
  <diet>Herbivore</diet>
  <period>Jurassic</period>
 </dinosaur>
 <dinosaur>
  <name>Tyrannosaurus</name>
  <group>Saurischia</group>
  <diet>Carnivore</diet>
  <period>Cretaceous</period>
 </dinosaur>
 </dinosaurs>
```

I want to put the names into an unsorted list

My code:

```
var inner = '';
    $(xml).find('dinosaurs').each(function(){
        $(this).find('dinosaur').each(function(){
            $(this).find("name").each(function(){
             var name = $(this).text();
             inner += "<li>"+name+"</li>";
            }
        }
    }
```

This outputs absolutely nothing, could somebody show me where i went wrong?
Please and thank you

Comment: @SteveWellens but $(xml).find('dinosaurs').find('dinosaur').find("name").text(); prints out every name in a single line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var xml = "<dinosaurs> <dinosaur>  <name>Staurikosaurus</name>  <group>Saurischia</group>  <diet>Carnivore</diet>  <period>Triassic</period> </dinosaur> <dinosaur>  <name>Diplodocus</name>  <group>Saurischia</group>  <diet>Herbivore</diet>  <period>Jurassic</period> </dinosaur> <dinosaur>  <name>Stegosaurus</name>  <group>Ornithischia</group>  <diet>Herbivore</diet>  <period>Jurassic</period> </dinosaur> <dinosaur>  <name>Tyrannosaurus</name>  <group>Saurischia</group>  <diet>Carnivore</diet>  <period>Cretaceous</period> </dinosaur> </dinosaurs>";

var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);

var inner = '';
$(xmlDoc).find('dinosaurs').each(function ()
{
    $(this).find('dinosaur').each(function ()
    {
        $(this).find("name").each(function ()
        {
            var name = $(this).text();
            inner += "<li>" + name + "</li>";
        });   
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this. But actually i found that literally all i needed to add was the ")" to close the "each" functions. So .parseXML(xml) is actually unnecessary.